# Global ObjectContext or local one?

Tags: entity-framework, entity, objectcontext

I'm starting with the Entity Framework and the repository pattern. I'm confused about the ObjectContext.
Is it better to instantiate it each time we need it?
I'm using like that:

```
        private GenericRepository _genericRepository;

        public EmployeeDAO()
        {
            var _context = new NorthwindEntities();
            this._genericRepository = new GenericRepository(_context);
        }

        public Employee FindByID(int employeeID)
        {
            Employee _employee = this._genericRepository.Single<Employee>(x => x.EmployeeID == employeeID );
            return _employee;
        }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is maintain the transaction with a static LINQ to SQL DataContext in asp.net possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324147/is-maintain-the-transaction-with-a-static-linq-to-sql-datacontext-in-asp-net-poss)

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653009/entity-framework-and-connection-pooling/3653392#3653392

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what exactly you mean by `Global`, but a singleton `ObjectContext` is not a good idea. The `ObjectContext` is a Unit of work, and should be pretty much short lived. The exact implementation details may depend on what kind of application you are developing. E.g. for a web application it is quite common to have one `ObjectContext` instance per web request.

You can also check out similar questions here:

[Entity Framework 4 ObjectContext Lifetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362280/entity-framework-4-objectcontext-lifetime)

[EF - and repository pattern - multiple contexts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3194185/ef-and-repository-pattern-multiple-contexts/3196196#3196196)